# How can i retrieve the row added to a table in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

i have a table with 3 attributes,(`Name`,`NoteName`,`NoteContent`).
if i would like to retrieve from the table only the last row that was inserted, is there a way to do that?
like for example i need something like this:

```
s.executequery("Select NoteName,NoteContent from usernotes Where Name='"     
+clientSentence+"'"); //but only the last row and not all the rows
```

Comment: Are you using JDBC? If so you should tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the last row inserted also has the largest primary key.

So, based that your usernotes may have a numerical ID, you could do something like this:

```
s.executequery("Select NoteName,NoteContent from usernotes Where Name='"     
+clientSentence+"' order by ID desc limit 1"); //but only the last row and not all the rows
```

Another option is to use `LAST_INSERT_ID` if you use autoincrement, see:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21188

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```